# Derivative of Complex Function that Satisfies Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

In my textbook, Advanced Engineering Mathematics, 7th ed., they take derivatives of complex functions two different ways in chapter 19.2, and I'm curious why both of them are appropriate.

The first time, it is to show that for $f(z) = e^z, f'(z) = e^z$.  They do this by defining $e^z$ as $u(x, y) = e^xcos(y)$ and $v(x, y) = ie^xsin(y)$.  They then take the derivative of both of these in the x direction, which obviously gives us the same thing since it's just the derivatives of $e^x$ that matter.

At a separate example, they do a similar process, but after defining $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$, they take $du/dx$ and $dv/dy$.  This is to show that the derivative of $cos(z) = -sin(z)$.

Why could we take the derivatives in the x direction for both u and v in the first example, but then take them in the x and y directions in the second ones?  This seems inconsistent to me.  Is it because we've satisfied the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so the direction along which we differentiate doesn't matter?

Thanks!

Comment: From the CRE, we have $v^y=u_x$ and $v_x=-u_y$.

Comment: Oh my goodness, of course.  Thank you for the help

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.